# Is is possible to copy folder structure without coping items?

Tags: outlook-redemption

Is it possible to copy folder structure without coping items? Or at least copy a folder without the items. Any suggestions if not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, even on the MAPI level, [IMAPIFolder.CopyFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapifolder-copyfolder) copies both items and hidden items. The only option is whether to copy the sub-folders (which Redemption always does).